# Como ver la linea donde se ejecuta el error en la consola

Tags: javascript, reactjs, console

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto en reactJs y cuando tengo errores que quiero ver en la consola, no aparece la linea donde se esta generando el error sino otros archivos que desconozco en mi proyecto. Lo que me dificulta conseguir rapidamente los errores.

Si alguien le ha pasado y me puede explicar como configurar esto para que me salgan mis archivos del proyecto en el cual trabajo y no esto.

Ej hice un console.log y me aparece este archivo:
**bundle.js:1566**  true

**VM128:236**  true

y esos no son mis archivos del proyecto.

Disculpen mi ignorancia pero estoy aprendiendo y es primera vez que me pasa.

Comment: Si no me equivoco, esto es un enlace: `VM128:236` que te muestra el ajax donde ha sucedido el problema, y con eso podrías identificar a que parte de tu código se corresponde con un poco de suerte.

Comment: @masterguru y porque no me muestra la linea del archivo en donde esta el problema o el console.log. Porque cuando doy click a ese enlace me aparece el codigo bien extraño nada parecido a lo que yo estoy haciendo y para mi es mas dificil asi

Comment: Pues quizás ese código que ves allí debe pertener a `bundle.js` seguramente, que por lo que sea estás usando en tu web (quizás forma parte de algun modulo de terceros que estés instalando que lo está llamando).  Mira en la consola si ves cargar ese bundle.js en alguna parte al recargar la página (no se reactjs, por lo tanto te hablo de esto como si fuera javascript y lo estuvieras ejecutando desde un navegador).

Comment: @masterguru y sabes donde puedo deshabilitar eso para que no aparezca mas y solo me muestre mis archivos?

Comment: React es codigo transpilado.. eso quiere decir, que tu codigo esta embebido dentro de funciones JS para que pueda ser ejecutado... Vos no queres ver esa linea, deberias analizar el error que te da React y trabajar sobre eso...